# Lie algebra that cannot be realised from the commutator bracket of an algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

What is an example of a Lie algebra that cannot be realised from the commutator bracket of an algebra?

Edit: More precisely, does every Lie algebra admit a faithful representation on a vector space. From the comment below, Ado's theorem says this is true for finite dimensional algebras. So are there infinite dimensional Lie algebras not admitting faithful representations?

Comment: [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) At least I hope that there is no contruction that makes $\mathbb{R}^3$ into algebra where the cross product is the commutator.

Comment: That's not an answer to your question, but do you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem ?

Comment: The infinite dimensional case is also covered by the Universal Enveloping Algebra, though that one is specifically made so this works.

Comment: You should not change your question after having received good answers. Moreover Ado's theorem also settles your changed question, and then again you are changing the question to the infinite-dimensional case and so on. That is not a good style.

Answer (score 2):

A semi-simple Lie algebra cannot be realized as the commutator bracket of an associative algebra. An associative algebra is a particular case of a left-symmetric algebra: these are algebra defined by:
$x(yz)-(xy)z=y(xz)-(yx)z$. For a left-semmetric algebra $A$, the bracket defined by $[x,y]=xy-yx$ is a Lie algebra. The Lie algebra associated to $A$ is not semi-simple. This is a corollary of the Whitehead Lemma.

The proof works like so: if $A$ is a left-symmetric, let $L(A)$ be the associated Lie algebra. Define $L_a(x)=ax$, the map $a\rightarrow L_a$ is a representation of $L_a$ and $Id_A$ is a $1$-cocycle for this representation since $ax-xa=[a,x]$. Withehead lemma implies that there exists $e\in A$ such that $ae=a$ for every $a\in A$.

Let $ad_e(x)=ex-xe=ex-x$, we have $Id_A=L_e+ad_e$, we deduce that $Trace(Id_A)=Trace(L_e)+Trace(ad_e)=0$ since $L(A)$ is semi-simple, the image of $L$ is contained in $sl(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: (+1) The first proof of this, before using Lie algebra cohomology, came from geometry, using  fixed point theorems.

Comment: Sorry but I am confused. $\frak{sl}_22$  is a semisimple Lie algebra and it is basically defined in terms of commutator brackets.

Comment: Wait I think I see your point. You are showing that there cannot exist a product on $\frak{g}$ such that the product implements the Lie bracket. I am asking something different, namely if there exists a faithful representation. I have altered the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Piet, no, $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ cannot be realised from a commutator bracket $[x,y]=x\cdot y-y\cdot x$ of some associative algebra $(A,\cdot)$. A faithful linear representation is something different - check your title! It says nothing about faithful (linear) representations.